# How to getQueryResults() of 1 job after createQueryJob() successfully in Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using google cloud big query service with nodejs client version 1.0x . I created a job successfully by function `createQueryJob()`. After that, I used an event listen when a callback create job response with `getQueryResults()` such as:

```
 const options = {
        query: sqlQuery,
        useLegacySql: true,
        dryRun: true
    };
    // this.bigquery is an constructor.
    // this.bigquery = new BigQuery({
    //    projectId: this.projectId,
    //   keyFilename: this.keyFile,
    // });
    this.bigquery.createQueryJob(options, function (err, job) {
        if (!err) {
            // job id such as 731bf23b-5044-4842-894b-4d9f77485d9b
            function manualPaginationCallback(err, rows, nextQuery, apiResponse) {
                if (nextQuery) {
                    job.getQueryResults(nextQuery, manualPaginationCallback);
                } else {
                    return Promise.resolve(rows);
                }
            }

            return job.getQueryResults({
                maxResults: 100000,
                autoPaginate: false,
                // timeoutMs : 60000
            }, manualPaginationCallback);
        }
    });
```

But It throw an error

> {"error":{"code":404,"message":"Not found: Job
>   [myProjectId]:731bf23b-5044-4842-894b-4d9f77485d9b","errors":[{"message":"Not
>   found: Job
>   [myProjectId]:731bf23b-5044-4842-894b-4d9f77485d9b","domain":"global","reason":"notFound"}],"status":"NOT_FOUND"}}

refrence

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigquery/1.0.x/BigQuery#createQueryJob
https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigquery/1.0.x/Job#getQueryResults

What wrong's with me? Any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the `dryrun` option in your request, which only validates the job but doesn't actually run the query.  Dryrun jobs don't persist, which is why you get not found on the subsequent request.